# git - does it work on image?

Tags: git

im actually working with git, i add without problem the entire directory where i'm building the website.
how git treat the images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source control software can treat binary files just fine, but some of the magic will not work for it. The main limitation is you cannot merge conflicts automatically. [Additionally, you cannot acquire locks on files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119444/locking-binary-files-using-git-version-control-system), so conflicts will eventually happen and they will have to be manually resolved before a `push` can take place.

Answer (score 0):

As binary files. WARNING: it can't automatically merge this files.