# How can I lock file from changes when using GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, push, git-commit

I'm using Visual Studio with GIT, I'd like to lock some project files to prevent any of team members to push any changes related to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to lock individual files or directories on fork when using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13662255/608639)

Answer (score 2):

With git alone, there is no built-in way to lock a file.

---

If you use a server (say `gitolite` or `gitlab`), the server may offer a way to do this :

- if found this link for [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/locking/)
- [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html) for gitlab (it appears to be a feature of the paying version)

---

Otherwise, you can program this feature on your own central repository, using [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) :

if you want to reject pushes on the central repository that modify a certain file, have a look at the [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_code_pre_receive_code) (you can search SO to look for uses of pre-receive hooks ;) )