# Is it possible to use File Locking from libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

1. Like the SVN Locked function, It can lock files when we push data to the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to lock individual files or directories on fork when using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662255/is-there-a-way-to-lock-individual-files-or-directories-on-fork-when-using-git)

Comment: This is too broad and doesn't have enough details on what exactly you want to do. It may depend heavily on OS and file system. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. Note also that svn lock only works with other svn clients, it doesn't prevent other programs from messing with the files.