# how to let only one person to check-in and check out GIT?

Tags: git

I have something to deal with , we are a big team working on one project and i need to let only one person working one file so if someone else open this file it wont let him change it tell i finish my work on it how can that be done ?

Comment: yeah, use Visual Source Safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locking binary files using git version control system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119444/locking-binary-files-using-git-version-control-system)

Comment: Locking files for exclusive access is a very old way of working. Things like `rcs` did that. Modern version control systems work using a merge concurrency model and since you've moved to git, you should embrace it rather than try to force it to behave like an old tool.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can lock a `src` (I guess it's a code file, and not a binary one) with Git. **Git** has little related to VSS, and if you wish to lock files, you should decide if using **Subversion** is a better aproach to solve your problems, since SVN does support file locking.

The idea of Git is letting you change anything you want and then, merging the changes multiple users have done to it.